# Why is physical optics an approximate technique?

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider the problem of known electromagnetic source in free space near a perfect electric conductor (PEC) object. Finding the total electromagnetic field in this situation can be done through solving Maxwell's equations numerically. At high frequencies, this becomes very computationally expensive in terms of time and memory. Approximate techniques like physical optics (PO) are then used.

PO in the above situation is based on finding the electric currents on the surface of the PEC object, getting the exact scattered field due to these currents, and adding it to the original fields radiated by the source.

From reading of various resources and references, it is always mentioned that PO has two inherently introduced approximations:

1. Ignoring the diffraction effect, which is complemented afterwards through methods like PTD (physical theory of diffraction.)
2. The PO current on the PEC surface is itself approximate.

What is the justification of point 2 above? Why is the PO current considered approximate, although it is calculated from a true boundary condition at the PEC surface?

Comment: I'm no expert. But it only applies where the object is electrically large compared to the wavelength and also essentially smooth. Some idea of 'lit' and 'unlit' regions are also necessary (not an easy task.) The asymptotic limit of Maxwell is applied. Javier Gutiérrez-Meana & José Á. Martínez-Lorenzo & Fernando Las-Heras write about the approximation issues in chapter 8 of the edited compilation called *"Electromagnetic Waves Propagation in Complex Matter"* from 2011. You might start there. Or go to the physics stackexchange site for better information and more detailed answers.

Comment: Thank you for your fruitful comment and resource suggestion.